# Exporting order from Woocommerce webhook to google sheets with app

Tags: wordpress, google-apps-script, google-sheets, woocommerce, webhooks

I found a google sheets app [script](https://www.tychesoftwares.com/export-woocommerce-orders-to-google-sheets-in-realtime/) to export orders from Woocommerce to google sheets using the Woocommerce webhook. After a small modification it looks like this:

```
//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a GET request
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("request received");
}

//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a POST request
function doPost(e) {
  var myData             = JSON.parse([e.postData.contents]);
  var order_created      = myData.date_created;
  var billing_email      = myData.billing.email;
  var total_items        = myData.total.items;
  var order_total        = myData.total;
  var order_number       = myData.number;


  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([order_created,billing_email,total_items,order_total,order_number]);
}
```

The script works well but I would like to export the total of items (all products/ SKU) in an order. This should be done with the line

> var total_items        = myData.total.items;

But it doesn't work unfortunately (it doesn't show any data). I guess it's due to the "myData.total.items" part of the line.

Can someone help me to correct this line?

Another question, can someone tell me how I can cut of the timestamp from the date. The results look like "2021-06-07T11:30:02" (I would like to cut off : T11:30:02)
Thanks

The situation at the moment in gsheets is: [image] ('items' is empty)

It should be like this: [image] This should calculate the qty of all items of an order not only the qty of 1 type of product of an order

```html
//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a GET request
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("request received");
}

//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a POST request
function doPost(e) {
  var myData             = JSON.parse([e.postData.contents]);
  var order_created      = myData.date_created.split("T")[0];
  var billing_email      = myData.billing.email;
  var total_items = 0
  for (var i=0;i<myData.line_items.length;i++){
    total_items+=myData.line_items[i].quantity
  }
  var order_total        = myData.total;
  var order_number       = myData.number;

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([order_created,billing_email,total_items,order_total,order_number]);
}
```

Comment: About your 1st question, can you provide the sample value of `myData.total.items` and the sample output value you expect? About your 2nd question, when you want to retrieve `2021-06-07` from `2021-06-07T11:30:02`, how about `console.log("2021-06-07T11:30:02".split("T")[0])`?

Comment: @Tanaike, pls see the samples in the post. Where do I put this line "console.log("2021-06-07T11:30:02".split("T")[0])" exactly? thnx

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about  the sample value of `myData.total.items` and the sample output value you expect. So, can you provide the sample value of `myData.total.items` and the sample output value you expect? And about `Where do I put this line "console.log("2021-06-07T11:30:02".split("T")[0])" exactly?`, in your situation, how about modifying `var order_created = myData.date_created;` to `var order_created = myData.date_created.split("T")[0];`?

Comment: If I can be some help ... could you provide a slice of the response of doGet that shows ... "total":{"items":"XXXX ... I haven't see this in woocommerce json samples !

Comment: @MikeSteelson and Tanaike, I edited (at the end) the post by adding 2 screenshots of  1. the current google sheets output and 2. how it should be. Don't know if these are visibile for you? I can see them from my end...

Comment: Yes I can see them but that does not answer my question of the existence of 'total.items' for which I have a doubt, that is why I would prefer to see the json resulting from the request. Without this information, I fear you will never have a substantial answer.

Comment: @MikeSteelson, I understand now, sorry, I get that from integromat (there it's called total_items  : totalLineItemsQuantity). But now I understand I should check this? https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#orders And here I can't find it...  only qty per line item :( any solution for this?

Comment: @MikeSteelson, thnx, although it didn't give me any data, could it be I used it wrong? Can you check if I modified it right (I put the modified version at the end of the post)?

Comment: Once again, we will be able to help when we will see the structure of the response of doGet. Here I have taken a json from https://www.tychesoftwares.com/export-woocommerce-orders-to-google-sheets-in-realtime/ and it works well.

Comment: @MikeSteelson, ran another test, it works, but only with orders with just one SKU /item. Orders with more then 1 SKU / item just don't show data in gsheets. Where do I get the  "structure of the response of doGet"?

Comment: can you provide Logger.log(e.postData.contents) for some examples ? Meanwhile, I will give you a tool to get all pairs in a json ...

Comment: @MikeSteelson, sorry, this is the point you kinda lost me ...  I have no idea :(

Comment: ok whatever, have you tried the getPairs function i post below?

Comment: I don't know how to do this but i ran your script and received the following? "Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'postData' of undefined
doPost @ Code.gs:2"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  var total_items = 0
  for (var i=0;i<myData.line_items.length;i++){
    total_items+=myData.line_items[i].quantity
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect that by this way you can easily read the structure of the complete json

```
function doPost(e) {
  var myData             = JSON.parse([e.postData.contents]);
  getPairs(eval(myData),'myData')
}
function getPairs(obj,id) {
  const regex = new RegExp('[^0-9]+');
  const fullPath = true
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  for (let p in obj) {
    var newid = (regex.test(p)) ? id + '.' + p : id + '[' + p + ']';
    if (obj[p]!=null){
      if (typeof obj[p] != 'object' && typeof obj[p] != 'function'){
        sheet.appendRow([fullPath?newid:p, obj[p]]);
      }
      if (typeof obj[p] == 'object') {
        getPairs( obj[p], newid );
      }
    }
  }
}
```